# all external requests/ping returns gateway as destination IP

Tags: server, internet, dns

"ping www.google.com" returns

PING www.google.com (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

and returns no response, obviously.

"ping www.yahoo.com" returns

PING www.yahoo.com (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

also, again, no response for obvious reasons.

When it did this the first time I thought that it was a problem with the DNS servers that my router was pointing to, so I changed the interfaces file to point to 8.8.8.8 instead for both eth0 and eth1.  Didn't help.  My computer thinks the entire internet is at 192.168.1.1.  I've never seen this before.  What is going on here?

Comment: Install `wireshark` (you may need to download the packages manually on a different computer), start a packet capture session and ping a new, preferably obscure site. Then stop the packet capture and try to follow the network conversation to UDP port 53. This will tell you which is the misbehaving DNS server (might be the local DNS cache `dnsmasq` in 14.04, might be your router or might be something else). Once you know that you have a chance of fixing it.

Comment: This is a server.  I don't have a GUI; CLI only.  I don't have a window manager installed, so I can't use wireshark, unfortunately.

Comment: then try `tshark`